# What is the equivalent of the Windows dir command on macOS?

Tags: windows, macos, cmd

Does macOS have a command to get list of folders and files in your directory

```
dir /b/s
```

Or a command to get file names and save to a text file

```
 dir /b/s/w *.jpg > "filename.txt"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `ls`? `ls /b/s`

Comment: maybe yes I don't know about mac so trying finding commands. Are they correct? and do they match my requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS is POSIX *compliant* so it contains the usual command line utilities found in Unix environments.

`ls /b/s` will list all files in the directory `/b/s`

`ls /b/s/w*.jpg > filename.txt` will list all files under `/b/s` starting with `w` and ending with `.jpg` and pipe the output onto a text file called `filename.txt`

Comment: @lit He is correctly (mis-)interpreting the switches meant to dir by OP as a directory path under MacOs. So this is a clarification but not an answer in the sense of the title

Comment: Yes, didn't realize they were switches, I thought OP meant that as an example of a directory path in macOS. I'll let the answer be for now.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -l` command will give you detailed information of the contents of your directory along with the permissions just like `dir` command.

Answer (score 1):

Use find (see `man find` in a terminal or https://ss64.com/bash/find.html)

```
find $PWD -type f -name "*.jpg" >"filename.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

ls /a

can be used check out

https://ss64.com for a full list